# Wine refuses to find "ssl" python module

Tags: python, ssl, pip, wine

First and foremost, I'm not a very experienced wine user.

Onto the problem. I want to run a Windows executable which in some way or another launches some sort of a python script (presumably, for authorization purposes). In this script, as evident from the error message, an import of "ssl" is present and it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ssl
```

I have found that ssl is by default bundled with python 2.6+. I have also found that installing/uninstalling any versions of python inside wine does not fix the issue. Furthermore, I can import ssl inside of wineconsole successfully and also on my linux installation with both python2 and python3.

I don't know how to solve this, but I have a guess that wine pulls python modules from somewhere else, although I haven't been able to find where from exactly and why.

Comment: What executable do you want to run?

Comment: @apilat Ableton Live 10. Oh, forgot to mention. It starts well on real windows 7.